# How to characteristize or distinguish those lacunary series with same natural boundary from each other

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

There are lots of different lacunary series with integral coefficients and with same natural boundary.

As we know,Some functions can be distinguished or characterized by their poles.

Now,the question is:how to characteristize or distinguish those lacunary series with same natural boundary from each other by informations of their behaviour near the boundary,that is asymptotic behaviour,or something like poles of function.Could we distinguish them or characterize them only by asymptotic behaviour